# Adding links to SVG elements in Python using SVGWRITE

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

I am trying to build an SVG that would feature lines, each line would link to a part elsewhere in the same document. I keep getting a `ValueError`, however, stating that "`Invalid children 'line' for svg-element <a>.`"

This MWE reproduces the error:

```
import svgwrite

test = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny',size=(100, 100))

link = test.add(test.a('http://stackoverflow.com'))
link.add(test.line(start=(0,0),end=(100,100)))

test.save()
```

I get the same error with other drawing elements (ellipsis, rect, etc), but these are certainly allowed as children of a link.

What am I missing?

Python version: 2.7.10
svgwrite version: 1.1.6 (reported by `pkg_resources`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) provides working code, but it is not idiomatic from what I've seen. And I think the suggestion that the syntax is "entirely wrong" is misleading (though I'm open to a more convincing demonstration).

Removing the profile specification in my example fixes it---and works as well in the larger project from which this minimal example was derived. This is not an entirely satisfactory answer to me, because I don't understand, based on reading the [tiny spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/) *why* links are causing this problem, but it is an answer, which achieves the desired result without departing from the typical uses of svgwrite that I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using entirely the wrong syntax for element creation in svgwrite.

According to the documentation links are created via a call to [svgwrite.container.Hyperlink](https://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/hyperlink.html) and lines via a call to [svgwrite.shapes.Line](https://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/shapes.html)

Once that's fixed you still won't see anything as a line without a stroke set is invisible. I've added a stroke and set the stroke width wider than normal below so there's something to click on.

```
import svgwrite

test = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', profile='tiny',size=(100, 100))

link = test.add(svgwrite.container.Hyperlink('http://stackoverflow.com'))
link.add(svgwrite.shapes.Line(start=(0,0),end=(100,100),stroke_width="5",stroke="black"))

test.save()
```

This produces the following output

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="tiny" height="100" version="1.2" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs /><a target="_blank" xlink:href="http://stackoverflow.com"><line stroke="black" stroke-width="5" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="100" /></a></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; the syntax in my MWE does work, calling the created objects rather than the module itself seems more typical from examples of svgwrite use you can find. (I'm not really a programmer, and esp. not a OO programmer). You're absolutely right that without specifying `stroke_width` and `color` nothing would be visible Your version works. But just removing `profile='tiny'` will also work.